# How to inject a computed property into every controller in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

If I set some actions and a computed property in the application controller and want to use the computed property in another controller, I currently have to set this property in every other controller manually.

This is how I am doing it now:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend
  isOn: true
  actions:
    on: ->
      this.set('isOn', true);
    off: ->
      this.set('isOn', false);

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend
  needs: ['application']
  isOn: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.application.isOn")
```

2 questions:

- How can I inject this into every controller that is automatically generated?
- Is this the best way to implement global actions/properties in Ember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you could use `reopenClass` to reopen `Ember.Controller` and extend it to do what you need.  I just tried it in a jsfiddle and I couldn't get that to work.

What I did get to work was `Ember.Mixin`.

```
App.IsOn = Ember.Mixin.create({
  needs: ['application'],
  isOn: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.application.isOn")
})

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend(App.IsOn,{});
```

It doesn't handle automatically generated controllers, but it does let you put the functionality into controller with just one line if you don't need the controller for anything else.

Here's a jsfiddle with everything working:

http://jsfiddle.net/DqeLv/

EDIT: I should also add that you want to have the `toggleOn` method in your `ApplicationRoute` instead of `ApplicationController`.  Bubbling of events goes from the most specific controller, then to the route for that controller, then up to each successive parent route (but not controller).

So, say you're at `"/users/new"` and trigger an action, it will go to :

`UsersNewController` => `UsersNewRoute` => `UsersRoute` => `ApplicationRoute`

EDIT #2:  OK, after getting some sleep I was able to get `reopen` to work so that auto generated controllers get the `isOn` property atuomatically.

```
Ember.Controller.reopen({
    needs: ['application'],
    isOn: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.application.isOn")
});
```

It seems that this only works for "generic" controllers, not for instances of `ArrayController` or `ObjectController` (only for routes that don't return a `model`).

If you want it to work for auto generated `ArrayController` and `ObjectController` instances you can `reopen` those two classes.

```
Ember.ArrayController.reopen({ ... })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HTPaF/2/

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am thinking that an `Ember.Application.initializer` may have been the better way to go but I wasn't able to get this to work with the `injection` or `typeInjection` functions. If you've got any thoughts on this, they would be appreciated, but I've marked your answer as correct as I can't see an alternative just yet.